# Get domain name of the page that includes script using <script>

Tags: php, http

I'm including a php script that renders some javascript like this:

```
<script src="http://example.net/somejsfile.php"></script>
```

How do I get the domain name of the page from which the script is being included? The objective is to only allow the script to be loaded on certain domains.

So imagine I'm including  on http://mystore.com/page1.html

What I want is to be able to extract mystore.com from inside http://example.net/somejsfile.php

Here is the print_r of the $_SERVER variable:

```html
 Array
(
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
    [REQUEST_URI] => /......
    [HTTPS] => on
    [SSL_TLS_SNI] => domain.com
    [HTTP_HOST] => domain.com
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => */*
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.5
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br
    [HTTP_COOKIE] => ....
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
    [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
    [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => ...

    [SERVER_NAME] => ....
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 192.168.1.51
    [SERVER_PORT] => 443
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => ....
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => ....
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => https
    [CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /....
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => [no address given]
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => ....
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 56852
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => ...
    [PHP_SELF] => /...
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1517979916.084
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1517979916
)
```

So as you can see $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] are no even an option. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a simple solution:

For example: `getprotectedscript.php`

```
<?php
  if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $your_allowed_origins))
    readfile("protected_directory/$your_script_file");
```

Remember to put a `.htaccess` in the `protected_directory`:

```
DENY FROM ALL
```

Finally, in the client, you will have to do this:

```
window.addEventListener('onload', async function() {
  const response = await fetch('getprotectedscript.php');
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.innerHTML = await response.text();
  document.body.appendChild(script);
})
```

Comment: But how would I get the $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] from the client? It's not passing that variable to me.